# Find index of an object that contains an object with a specific value

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of object 'YearGroup' called yeargroups. Each YearGroup has an array of object 'Student' called students.

In a function inside of a Student object, it is useful for me to know the index of the YearGroup it is in. How would I find this?

The below code is the example of this. I've made a similar function within YearGroup that finds it's own index in yeargroups, but how would I write a similar function within a Student?

```
class YearGroup {

    var id = UUID()
    var students = [Student]()
    var myIndex = 0

    func findMyIndex() {
        myIndex = yeargroups.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == self.id})!
    }

}

class Student {

    let id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var myYearGroupIndex = 0

    init(n:String, a:Int) {
        name = n
        age = a
    }

    func findMyYearGroupIndex() {
        myYearGroupIndex = ????????
    }

}

var yeargroups = [YearGroup]()
```

This code doesn't actually add any YearGroup or Student objects but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

Comment: This looks like a bad design, your YearGroup depends on an external object. What logic/value does the index of a YearGroup object represent?

Comment: Joakim Yeah I thought it might be a bit illogical. Basically, each Student will also have a function within it that says if myYearGroupIndex != 0, run the rest of the function. I can then say for Student in every YearGroup, run that function, and the Student object itself will figure out if it should. Now that I’m reading what I’ve written I think I’m realising there’s a much better way to write this as a function outside of the Student class. Any extra input would be greatly appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

As your code is right now a Student could be in any number of YearGroups. You could avoid potential confusion there by making the YearGroup a student is a member of a property of Student.

With that in place you can have the findMyYearGroupIndex() do a search like the one in YearGroup::findMyIndex().

If you really don’t want YearGroup to be a member of student you could pass it as an argument to findMyYearGroupIndex(groups: [YearGroups]).

Looking at this I’m not sure if YearGroups and the students make a 2 dimensional array. If so you need to store the index either as a pair (Int, Int) or an array with two elements [Int].

Sorry I don’t have code blocks in here. I can’t seem to make them on my phone.